# Has Iron Man made any suit for underwater combat?

Tags: marvel, comics, iron-man

Iron Man has made many suits and many of them serve some specific purpose like the Hulkbuster armor and the suit to fly in space, but has he made any suit which will help him in fighting underwater?

I want to ask about the Marvel comics and about suits specifically designed for underwater combat?

Comment: His 'standard' suit seems to work well enough under water: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6WH8mCKfaew

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In *Iron Man* Issue 218 we see he has created a suit, the Iron Man Armor Model 6 or Hydro Armor, specifically to go underwater in.

[image: Iron Man 218 page showing the first appearance of the Hydro Armor] [image: Iron Man 218 page showing Iron Man fighting underwater]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

In *Avengers Vol 8* Issue 9 we see Iron Man Armor Model 61 which he uses specifically to fight underwater in.

[image: Avengers Vol 8 9 showing the Armor Model 61 fighting underwater]

In the *Iron Manual* we see his Deep Submergence Suit.

[image: Iron Manual showing the Deep Submergence Suit] [image: Iron Manual showing the Deep Submergence Suit in more detail]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

---

In the MCU Tony's armours seem to cope reasonably well underwater. In *The Avengers* we see him out at sea underwater fixing the pipeline.

In *Iron Man 3* we see the Hammerhead armour as part of the House Party Protocol.

[image: Iron Man 3 showing the Hammerhead armour]

It is region locked so I can't download the app but the *Iron Man 3 - JARVIS: A Second Screen Experience* app [apparently](https://ironman.fandom.com/wiki/Mark_XXXVII_-_Hammerhead) describes this armour as:

> Deep Sea Diving Suit designed for extreme pressure and traveling at high-speeds underwater. Features upgraded work-lights for high visibility.

Comment: It was specified this was about the comics later but as I'd already added the MCU part I'll leave it to be complete.

Comment: We see his Hydro-armor in the Ironman animated series and also in the recent Avengers Assemble animated series when they are fighting Attuma (the warlord from Atlantis)

Comment: love it that the armour has a second, clear bubble helmet on top of his usual one (which is already water tight)!

Comment: @Shreedhar Aye, I left those out as the question is about the comics only.

Comment: @thelethalcarrot do these suits help in swimming underwater at high speed

Comment: @codeczar they appear to, I’ll have a look when I’m back at a PC if there’s any explicit evidence.

Comment: I just wanna say that "Iron Manual" is the best, dumbest Marvel Comicism I could have read today. 10/10.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot what about the swimming specification

Comment: @codeczar The Deep Submergence Suit makes mention of how it pulls in water and shoots it out for swimming as you can see in the above images

Comment: AHH the rubber duckie